# Prove or disprove: $f \circ g$ is onto $\Bbb R$ then g is onto $\Bbb R$.

Tags: calculus, functions

Prove or disprove: $f \circ g$ is onto $\Bbb R$ then g is onto $\Bbb R$.
I am tending towards disproving it, but I have no idea how, I saw here a few examples with discrete groups and the integers, but I have no idea.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R},f(x)=\ln x$

$g:\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty),g(x)=e^x$